# Function crashing in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, xml-parsing

That´s all, it simply crashes before showing alert number 1:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: basePath+'mostrarMenu.do',
                dataType: "html",
                success: parseXml
              });

function parseXml(xml) {
        var menu = jQuery(xml).find("item");
        alert("0");
        menu.each(function(i, value) {
            alert("1");
            var setere = jQuery(value).find("name")[0].innerHTML;
            alert("2");
            if ( setere == '<!--[CDATA[menuDiv]]-->') {
                jQuery('#menuDiv').append(jQuery(value).find("value")[0].innerHTML);
            }
        });

    }
```

Any help or recommendation would be appreciated, patience with me, I am a zombie at this point of the day.

Comment: You have two `alert("1");` in there, it doesn't reach either?

Comment: uoch sorry, I was talking about the first "1"

Comment: crash means that it do not do anything without showing errors

Comment: I know, but I could not find any other word to describe this behavior. I have worked in game testing, and I know what crash means, especially in Fif*, medal of ***, etc jajaj

Answer (score 1):

You should call `$($.parseXML(xmlString))` instead of parsing the XML as HTML.